# python for loop cycles through value not in range specified

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a python code that contains a list `dict`, where each element is a list of arbitrary size. I am looping over the elements as follows:

```
for i in range(len(dict)):
    for j in range(1,len(dict[i])):
        str = dict[i][j]
```

at this point, I get an error saying `IndexError: list index out of range`. I am using `range(1,len(dict))` because I want to skip the first element of each list in `dict`. At the point the error is generated, `i=5`, `len(dict[5])=2`, so `j` should be looping over only `1`, but when I check the `j` value, I get `2`. How is this possible?

What's even weirder is that when I type the above code in the python console, I get no such error and everything works fine.

**Edit: the full code is: (note the change from `dict` to `keywords`)**

```
import re

conds = [['emerald cryo i&ii,a,01', '40% (v/v) mpd', 'sodium phosphate dibasic', 'citric acid'],['emerald cryo i&ii,a,02', '40% (v/v) ethylene glycol', 'sodium acetate', 'acetic acid'],['emerald cryo i&ii,a,03', '50% (v/v) peg-200', 'citrate', 'na']]

keywords = [["'sodium acetate'", " 'sodium acetate'", " 'na(ac)'", " 'na acetate'", " 'na_acetate'"],["'rbcl+mgcl2'", " 'rbcl+mgcl2 (0.025m each)'"]]

#cycle through elements to see if there is a match to the dictionary
for i in range(len(keywords)):
    for j in range(1,len(keywords[i])):
        print j
        for k in range(len(conds)):
            str = keywords[i][j].strip().strip("'").strip() #this is where the error occurs
            match = [(str == l) for l in conds[k]]
            ind = [i for i, x in enumerate(match) if x]
            if len(ind) !=0:
                print ind
                print str
```

The actual `conds` and `keywords` lists are lot longer and being read in from a file, but I just copied and pasted two elements each from the python console.

Edit 2: printed out `i`, `j`, `len(dict[i])`, `dict[i]` in the inner loop. The output is too long to put here, but here is a condensed version:

```
0 1 3 ["'potassium acetate'", " 'k(oac)'", " 'potassium acetate'"]
3 1 3 ["'ammonium nitrate'", " '(nh4)2(no)3'", " 'ammonium nitrate'"]
3 1 3 ["'ammonium nitrate'", " '(nh4)2(no)3'", " 'ammonium nitrate'"]
3 1 3 ["'ammonium nitrate'", " '(nh4)2(no)3'", " 'ammonium nitrate'"]
4 1 5 ["'sodium acetate'", " 'sodium acetate'", " 'na(ac)'", " 'na acetate'", " 'na_acetate'"]
4 1 5 ["'sodium acetate'", " 'sodium acetate'", " 'na(ac)'", " 'na acetate'", " 'na_acetate'"]
5 1 2 ["'rbcl+mgcl2'", " 'rbcl+mgcl2 (0.025m each)'"]
4 1 5 ["'sodium acetate'", " 'sodium acetate'", " 'na(ac)'", " 'na acetate'", " 'na_acetate'"]
4 1 5 ["'sodium acetate'", " 'sodium acetate'", " 'na(ac)'", " 'na acetate'", " 'na_acetate'"]
3 1 3 ["'ammonium nitrate'", " '(nh4)2(no)3'", " 'ammonium nitrate'"]
3 1 3 ["'ammonium nitrate'", " '(nh4)2(no)3'", " 'ammonium nitrate'"]
4 1 5 ["'sodium acetate'", " 'sodium acetate'", " 'na(ac)'", " 'na acetate'", " 'na_acetate'"]
[2]
sodium acetate
4 1 5 ["'sodium acetate'", " 'sodium acetate'", " 'na(ac)'", " 'na acetate'", " 'na_acetate'"]
4 1 5 ["'sodium acetate'", " 'sodium acetate'", " 'na(ac)'", " 'na     acetate'", " 'na_acetate'"]
5 1 2 ["'rbcl+mgcl2'", " 'rbcl+mgcl2 (0.025m each)'"]

...

5 2 2 ["'rbcl+mgcl2'", " 'rbcl+mgcl2 (0.025m each)'"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "coarseCondEdit.py", line 38, in <module>
    str = keywords[i][j].strip().strip("'").strip()
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: list named `dict`. Why?

Comment: ...why is `dict` a list? This is confusing. Show your `dict` contents perhaps.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I know it's confusing out of context, but it contains a list of keywords with possible synonyms. Since there are more than one string corresponding to each keyword, and I am reading those from a file, it was more convenient to use lists rather than a dictionary. It's just a name. Is it a reserved keyword that can't be used as a var?

Comment: @AlexeyGorozhanov no, dict is not a keyword. List if keywords can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords)

Comment: Are you adding or removing any items from `dict` at any point during this loop?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I changed the name and I get the same error

Comment: @Kevin No, I am not.

Comment: @sodiumnitrate it's a reserved keyword, but you can use it as a variable name. It would shadow built-in dict though.

Comment: It's an interesting problem, but I don't think I can investigate any farther without an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Is there any chance that the same lists are shared between different dict values, so you _think_ you're not changing the value you're enumerating, but you actually are?

Comment: Meanwhile, `dict` isn't a reserved word that can't be used as a variable name, and neither is `str`, but using them is still a bad idea, behind that hides the names of the types. If you later want to write `s = str(i)` or `d = dict(*pairs)`, you're going to get a confusing error because you're trying to call your string object or list object instead of the `str` or `dict` constructors. And, of course, you're confusing everyone who reads your code, and making them have to think twice as hard to follow it, which is a bad idea when you want people to find a problem for you.

Comment: One last suggestion: add a `print i, j, len(dict[i]), dict[i]` inside the inner loop, right before the line that fails, and look at (and show us) what it prints out. That should make it obvious where things are going wrong.

Comment: @Kevin edit coming up in a minute

Comment: As an aside, you could do `for i in keywords:` followed by `for j in i[1:]` where i and j ar now the lists and skip the indexing.;

Comment: @tdelaney I'd say `i` and `j` are alright names for numbers in some circumstances (like matrix indexes), but I don't think they're ever good for collections.

Comment: @StefanPochmann - agreed. The comment was intended to show a different way to process the lists. I think it would have been less clear if I had also invented new names.

Comment: @tdelaney Hmm, I did do it in my answer. I find it *more* clear, as probably many people think "index" when they see "i/j". Using nice words makes it clearer that that's not the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line

```
ind = [i for i, x in enumerate(match) if x]
```

changes your `i` that you use for the outer loop.

That btw wouldn't have happened if you used normal Python looping instead of indexed looping:

```
for words in keywords:
    for word in words[1:]:
        for cond in conds:
            word = word.strip().strip("'").strip()
            match = [(word == l) for l in cond]
            ind = [i for i, x in enumerate(match) if x]
            if len(ind) !=0:
                print ind
                print word
```

Doesn't that also look much nicer and more meaningful?

The variable names could be further improved, but I'll leave that up to you as I don't know proper names for your things.

Comment: I can't believe I overlooked that. Thanks!

Comment: @sodiumnitrate Also note the code and text that I just added to my answer.